# Run wine headless on a docker to run a windows application

Tags: ssh, wine, docker, xvfb

I want to run a windows application(pyinstaller.exe) on a dockerized Linux (on Linux host), using wine, but I do not have a display connected. I just have an SSH terminal to the host Linux.
I am aware of the Xvfb solution, but since I need it on the Dockerfile, I am somewhat confused here.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Are you running Ubuntu? To make it easier to troubleshoot your issue, please edit your question and include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks